# VBA code that concatenates a letter and variable to create a cell reference

Tags: vba, excel

I have a piece of code that determines the lowest row with data in it. I want to write to the cell underneath this row so that I don't overwrite old data, but I'm having trouble referencing this cell. To clarify, I already have code that determines, for example, that the 51st row is the lowest row to contain data. I need to correct my second piece of code which writes to the cell below that row:

Note: The integer "highest" is the row number lowest on the table that contains data

```
    sh1.Range(Concatenate(",'B', (highest+1),")).Value
```

I also tried

```
    sh1.Range("B" & (highest+1)
```

Finally, I checked several forums and they hinted that I should use indirect to create a cell reference, but I haven't had much luck with that. What would the correct way to do this be?

Comment: `sh1.Range("B" & highest + 1).Value = "xxx"` should work assuming sh1 is a sheet, what happens when you try?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're very close, remove the second ( from this line

```
sh1.Range("B" & (highest+1)
```

So that it reads like this:

```
sh1.Range("B" & highest + 1)
```

Comment: Wow, just a single bracket from my answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can also use offset:

```
sh1.Range("B" & highest).Offset(1,0)
```